# Why does egrep -o not return the entire match?

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file "foo" with the following in it.:

```
mPosixHello
mPosixWorld
mPosix->ThisWontPrint()
mPosix.NorWillThis()
```

From the command line, I type:

```
egrep 'mPosix\B+' foo
```

As one would expect, it returns:

```
mPosixHello
mPosixWorld
```

Now, let's change the command to:

```
egrep -o 'mPosix\B+' foo
```

The output return is not what I would expect:

```
mPosix
mPosix
```

Why is this?  I am expecting to see the same output as the first run.  I thought -o prints out the actual substring that matched and not the entire line (in this case, they are the same thing aside from newline?   Hmmm...)

Some useful info:

```
> egrep --version
egrep (GNU grep) 2.12


> uname -a
Linux TSU-Debian-Dev 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any insight is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Since the 'why' question has been answered already, I'll post this as comment: Judging by your "code", it looks like you're looking for a regexp similar to `egrep -o 'mPosix[a-zA-Z0-9]+' foo`

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I'm just lazy, and thought I could do it the o ther way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\B is not a character class.  it is the [word boundry](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) anchor similar to $ (end of line) or ^ (start of line)

Anchors are a different breed. They do not match any character at all. Instead, they match a position before, after, or between characters. They can be used to "anchor" the regex match at a certain position.

TLDR;

anchors != character classes,

\b and \B basically ignore + and *

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks.  I like the analogy with start/end line.  I thought it was a glorified [..] 'underneath'.  Thanks for clarifying that for me.